# What is the Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) for Automator workflow?

Tags: macos, cocoa, automator

I tried to find it to use in the file open panel, but failed. Would you please inform me if you happen to know it? Thanks!

Comment: Note: `kUTTypeScript` does *not* apply to Automator `.workflow` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `com.apple.automator-workflow`.

```
$ mdls test.workflow
...
kMDItemContentType             = "com.apple.automator-workflow"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "com.apple.automator-workflow",
    "com.apple.package",
    "public.directory",
    "public.item"
)
...
```